# Ubuntu 64-bit 12.04 installation dvd boot problem blank screen

Tags: 12.04, installation, drivers, nvidia, nouveau

I get blank screen when trying to install UbuntuStudio 64-bit DVD (i tried to install from DVD not USB stick). When using nosplash and no quiet i see that it hangs when it tries to load the nouveau driver for my GeForce GT 630 so it looks like there is a problem with support for my graphics card.

After installation, I tried to install the binary nvidia current driver from package manager, but then, i just get a text terminal after rebooting.

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I'm running a GT 630 now with 12.10 64bit

I got a 'blank screen' well, I got a large looking login screen, then when I logged in, I got a single (I have dual monitors) screen with nothing on it but the background. I figured out later I must have been in 640X480 mode or something...

I ended up logging in with my laptop, killing lightdm (wich stops the X server), unstalling noeveau and installing the 310.19 version of the driver I downloaded from nVidia.

I seem to be running OK with 2 screens. I'm not sure if all the nifty GLX capabilities are supported though...I got a realy poor fps on glx gears, but the displays seem fairly ok.

OR...you could check out this tactic...this also might have worked for me instead of ssh into my box from my laptop.

https://askubuntu.com/a/204788/113252

Hope this helps.