# Do Nvidia's drivers work in 12.10 on a MacBook Pro?

Tags: 12.10, nvidia, macbook

**UPDATE: Since this question has got many views, I just want to add that from Ubuntu 13.04 onwards, proprietary drivers installed perfectly on my MacBook. Versions of Ubuntu prior to 13.04 will have problems**

I recently upgraded to 12.10 and was just checking for proprietary drivers to be installed. I found this in software sources

[image: Additional Drivers]

When I enabled Nvidia binary Xorg driver, unity disappears along with the launcher and everything. I just have the wallpaper. I did manage to open the terminal and open software sources and select the nouveau display driver which fixed it.

Question is how to enable NVIDIA binary Xorg driver and have everything working?

Hardware: Apple MacBook Pro 9,1 Mid 2012 15 inch non-retina. NVIDIA GeForce GT650M

EDIT: I tried the solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202677/nvidia-driver-doesnt-work-in-12-10). And now, when I boot into Ubuntu, I get a blinking cursor. That's all! No tty1, nothing. help !!

EDIT 2: I inserted the Live USB and re installed Ubuntu without formatting the partition. At least, I didn't lose my files, but all softwares are gone. And the output of

```
lspci -vnn | grep '\''[030[02]]'
```

is

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:0fd5] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
```

EDIT 3: So, I was checking the link which Shrinivas gave, namely this one http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/ubuntu-quetzal-nvidia.html and it doesn't work for me. Specifically, where he says to run the command `modprobe nvidia_current`, I get the output

```
FATAL: Error inserting nvidia_current (/lib/modules/3.5.0-22-generic/updates/dkms/nvidia_current.ko): Operation not permitted
```

So, what's the problem? To reiterate, I'm using Ubuntu on an `Apple MacBook Pro Mid 2012 15 inch non retina 8GB RAM with NVIDIA GeForce GT650M`

Comment: Possible duplicate of : [Nvidia driver doesn't work in 12.10](http://askubuntu.com/questions/202677/nvidia-driver-doesnt-work-in-12-10?rq=1)

Comment: I followed the steps there and now Ubuntu doesn't boot!! I just get a blinking cursor on boot! Please help

Comment: can you please add the output of: lspci -vnn | grep '\''[030[02]\]'

Comment: done. pls see edits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NVIDIA drivers install without a fuss on MacBooks on Ubuntu 13.04 and above.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here with new kernel update to 3.5.0-21
You can run the terminal from a F##! up unity by keyboard shortcut ctrl+alt+t
Then you can run the command `software-center` to launch the software center or `google-chrome` to launch the chrome internet browser (better than anything ^^)
Install linux-headers-3.5.0-21-generic from software-center (I'm on x64)
download the 310.19 version of the driver on Nvidia's website

```
Ctrl+F1
```

login with user + psw

`cd Downloads` (or whatever path you downloaded your nvidia####.run file)

```
sudo service lightdm stop
```

`sudo sh nvidia.run` (I renamed the nvidia install file to "nvidia.run" when downloading) I think I did say yes afterward to everything in the installation process

```
sudo reboot
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

This is my output to your command in the terminal:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GF106 [GeForce GTS 450] [10de:0dc4] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
```

Actually it seems that nvidia drivers don't fit in ubuntu 12.10. I installed from PPA

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current nvidia-settings
```

This PPA will install all the missing packages (dkms fakeroot linux-source linux-headers-generic linux-headers 3.5.0-17-generic...). I did it yesterday after several attempts with the proprietary drivers and, for now, it works pretty well. If you do not find other solution, give this one a try. Bye!

Comment: Several attempts? What happened each time?

Comment: I had to use nvidia-experimental 310.14 to get nvidia blobs to work on my MacBookPro9,1. But after sleeping/resume, I get a black screen. I did find a fix, but it seemed complex and so I stayed with nouveau.

Comment: Even with nouveau, I can't resume after sleep. I have to shut down everytime. Are you able to do it?

Comment: @beppe all the packages you mentioned were installed. Doesn't help.

Comment: @pratnala: Yes, my macbook pro 9,1 sleeps nicely with nouveau. Linux rex 3.7.5-030705-generic #201301280206 SMP Mon Jan 28 07:07:29 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux. I can not boot using grub: instead I use Apple's EFI boot (hold down Option when power on) and select 'Windows' or Linux partition.

Comment: This is my experience to date. http://philatwarrimoo.blogspot.com.au/2012/10/installing-ubuntu-1210-on-macbookpro91.html Please read throught it all before starting as I revert back to 3.5 kernel since 3.6 is not so good.

Comment: I already have Ubuntu running but without resume capability making me shutdown everytime >.< However, it seems that you installed Ubuntu in EFI Mode. Mine is a triple boot (OS X + Windows + Ubuntu) and apparently, it is not possible to triple boot all of them in EFI mode. So, mine is the BIOS way

Answer (score 0):

Install the linux sources and headers. These are required to build the driver.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-source linux-headers-3.5.0-17-generic
```

Then unistall any nvidia drivers you have installed.

```
sudo apt-get remove nvidia-current
```

Then reinstall the nvidia driver

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

Then restart the computer

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

It should now boot up using the nvidia drivers.

Comment: I did this and ubuntu won't boot. I just got a blinking cursor. No tty1, 2 or anything.

Comment: If grub's menu appears, select 2nd option - something like other or rescue - and boot to a shell or try safe-mode. Then remove nvidia packages and try again.

Comment: @philcolbourn It got stuck in recovery too

Answer (score 0):

Downloading the Drivers directly from NVidia and building it worked for me.

Comment: This would be a good answer if you can describe what you did and how you would 'build' the driver.

Comment: Can you explain the process in detail? I am kind of an Ubuntu noob

Answer (score 0):

Please see this:

http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/ubuntu-quetzal-nvidia.html

He gives a detailed explanation for installing proprietary nVidia drivers.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: This still doesn't work. See my edited question please.

Answer (score 0):

It seems sleep process is much more complicated in such cases..try hibernate against that.as I found it better option or alternative solution.

see [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/180776/82136) if you prefer to hibernate