# Ubuntu 12.10 on Macbook Pro 9,1

Tags: 12.10, macbook-pro

I am attempting an install of Ubuntu 12,10 on a non retina MacBook Pro 9,1. This is an Ubuntu only install without the use of refit or refind. 
The install disc boots and the installation proceeds without any problems. Once complete, I bless the boot partition under OSX from the install media and reboot.

Upon rebooting, I get dumped to a black screen with flashing cursor. From this [ask](https://askubuntu.com/questions/207578/do-nvidias-drivers-work-in-12-10) thread, it sounds like the Nvidia drivers are failing. Attempted this driver installation through a chroot mount to no avail.

I am convinced the boot failure has more to do with EFI that graphics drivers. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Just in case some one else stumbles across this and is left without an answer, the trick here is to interupt boot at grub2 by holding down the left shift key.
Once at the grub screen, select your kernel and prese 'e'.
Scroll down to the line with the kernel and somewhere around 'quiet' and 'nosplash' insert 'noapic'.  Press F10 to boot.

Once logged in, get to a terminal...

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:mactel-support/ppa
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install applesmc-dkms macfanctld
```

Reboot

I had to interrupt grub2 one last time to insert `noapic`.
Once logged in, I grabbed all my updates with...

`sudo apt-get -y dist-upgrade`

Wireless instructions can be found here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro9-2/Quantal