# nVidia GT 220 not working properly with Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: nvidia, 12.10

I used to enable proprietary nVidia drivers on every previous Ubuntu release to get it working properly (otherwise I was stuck with very low resolution and no graphic acceleration).  In particular, I noticed that the GPU fan runs at high speed all the time unless the video drivers are installed.

Today I installed 12.10.  Running the Live CD, surprisingly, everything was working fine: full resolution, acceleration, silent fan, and so on. The running driver was nvidia-current (GT 216).

After installing and booting, I found that the fan was spinning too fast. The installed driver is nouveau. I tried installing nvidia-current, or any other proprietary driver, even installing the kernel headers & source and then the drivers (as suggested in [Nvidia driver doesn't work in 12.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202677/nvidia-driver-doesnt-work-in-12-10)) - but the proprietary drivers are not working.  Now, unity and compiz refuse to start, low resolution, no acceleration, and fan on high.

Does anybody how to get the proprietary drivers working from here?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this driver http://www.geforce.com/drivers/results/58596 for NVIDIA GeForce GT 220 (http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gt-220)