# Graphics issues nvidia GTX 560 Ti

Tags: nvidia, gpu

I have a Asrock z77 Extreme 4 with a nvidia GTX 560 Ti video graphics card and I recently bought built it about six months ago. I have installed Ubuntu 12.10 64-bit on it (I installed the 32-bit first).

Over all, the graphics look pretty good, but there are a few issues I wanted to see about fixing:

When getting into Software Center there are major glitches in the icons and the text. I am able to use it, but in a lot of cases I am not able to read the details or reviews of the software information page.

It also does something similar every once in a while with other programs, such as file manager, Library Office, and System Settings but not near as often as the Software Center.

It freezes when using Super+S.

I have done a lot of research and stuff but I can not find the solution. I know it has to do with the graphics drivers and I tried following the directions from this link because it claimed to work with my graphics card but when I rebooted I got a black screen so I just ran the install disk again http://podzemski.com/2012/10/20/ubuntu-12-10-nvidia-drivers/.

I have tried other methods that changed the aspect ratio and the resolution and made it look really grainy [Nvidia driver doesn't work in 12.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202677/nvidia-driver-doesnt-work-in-12-10). My proper aspect ratio and resolution is 1920x1080 (16:9)

I have run all the updates and everything is up to date. There are no additional drivers that it asks for, or anything like that.

I am familiar with Ubuntu but I am no where near an expert.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Just in case, what Nvidia driver version are you using, what monitor/TV are you using and have you tried a lower resolution like 1680x1050?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a nvidia card and want proper use of it you will need the nvidia driver! Concentrate your efforts there. Is there something 'not standard' about where/how your graphics card is installed? E.g. I used to have a motherboard that listed the pci numbers backwards. The nvidia installer can fall down in such cases, especially with 2 graphics cards. If you get a black screen

```
Ctrl+Alt+F2
```

login and attempt to fix/work out what is going on. If necessary you can uninstall the nvidia driver and reboot to get back to x.