# nvidia driver not working on dell precision m6500

Tags: 12.10, drivers, nvidia, dell

So I have tried the steps outlined in this article [Nvidia driver doesn't work in 12.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202677/nvidia-driver-doesnt-work-in-12-10) but still to no avail. My screen normally pops up as just what’s on the desktop and the mouse, the only way to get out of it is to either uninstall the nvidia driver or change it back to the original graphics driver. I do get an error that says "Plymouth unmounted" or something like that when it loads up. This is my first time ever using Ubuntu (I have 12.10 installed) so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: okay so I had it working for about two hrs from following the instructions from Kay listed in the comments.

But then it all went haywire, so I redid the steps but nothing worked. I even tried doing this with a fresh install of ubuntu.

When I run the "nvidia-settings" command, I get an error that says I am not using nvidia driver(or something along those lines) run nvidia-xconfig and that doesn't work either 

I also am not sure if this matters but my Nvidia is a G92[Quadro FX 3800] and its on a 64 bit system of Ubuntu 12.10

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Remove the existing driver Codes:

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-current 
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-current-updates
```

Install NVIDIA driver Codes:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

Then restart the computer and run this:

```
nvidia x server settings
```

If you get **"nvidia: command not found"**; then run this:

```
nvidia-settings
```

Done!

Comment: Thanks for the help! it seems to be working now. However im not sure what the point to the nvidia-settings command was haha