# Nvidia GTX 680 drivers

Tags: 12.10, drivers, nvidia, graphics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Nvidia driver doesn’t work in 12.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202677/nvidia-driver-doesnt-work-in-12-10)

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 12.10 on my PC. But i cannot find the correct drivers for my videocard. I tried all the drivers in software sources. and i also tried a couple PPAs. My other computer with a Nvidia GTX 650 works great with the ubuntu-x-swat PPA.

Do any of you know how to get the videocard to work?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to [Nvidia's drivers page](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us) and download your video card's specific driver.

Just download the installer and run it under root permissions

Please note that you might have to run it while your X desktop is not running -  to do so just type

`service lightdm stop`

and run the installer.