# Updating Ubuntu destroys Unity

Tags: unity, 12.10, updates

I came back from vacations and installed the updates available for Ubuntu 12.10 as I always do. The system asked me to reboot and when I did it started again but in the screen some artifacts appeared (which may mean it's a vga driver problem). When the desktop showed up, the resolution was smaller and the Unity launcher and the systray had disapeared. All I could do was to open the terminal with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>. The buttons to close and minimize in the terminal windows had disapeared as well.

To fix the problem I reinstalled Ubuntu 12.10 by formatting the PC but when I installed the updates again the same thing happened which means that I can't do it again because the result will be the same.

Anyone knows what to do?

Thanks!

Comment: Please identify what video card you have. This is almost certainly a bug report.

Comment: I can just speculate without you posting actual error logs. Lately there have been many problems like this with nvidia drivers. If so `sudo apt-get install synaptic`, `sudo synaptic` and in the software sources select test the nvidia graphics driver.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen My video card is a Zotac GeForce GTX 550Ti. I installed the drivers using [this method](http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/11/install-nvidia-31019-linux-driver-in.html?m=0)

Comment: This answear fixed the problem for me

http://askubuntu.com/questions/202677/nvidia-driver-doesnt-work-in-12-10