# Install drivers

Tags: drivers

I'm currently using Ubuntu 12.10 64bit alongside with Windows 7 Professional 64bit on a custom hardware desktop PC, and I've noticed that I don't have the correct drivers for Ubuntu, since I'm experiencing some graphical and sound glitches.

So... how can I install the correct drivers for my pc without affecting my Windows 7 drivers, that's pretty much it.
Thanks
Ps: My hardware is:   (sorry for not having this here in the first place)

- Grapics Card: Nvidia GeForce GTS 450
- Motherboard: Asus P7P55 LX
- CPU: Intel Core i5-650

Comment: It would be good to first know what hardware you need drivers for. The things we would need are: Motherboard Make/Model
CPU Model
GPU Make/Model

Comment: Hi friend, can you add what Video card you have (Model, and such). That way it will be easier to help you. Also read here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/newest-nvidia-card-what-driver-should-i-install/61433#61433

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ubuntu drivers will not affect your windows drivers in *any* way whatsoever.

The [additional drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47506/how-do-i-install-extra-drivers) tool should do the trick for most things, though with 12.10 it may need a little additional help (read on!).

Unfortunately there's some minor issues with the way ubuntu 12.10 is set up (basically, the packages needed to build a [dkms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Kernel_Module_Support) module arn't pulled in automatically, so its just a [tiniest bit more difficult](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202677/nvidia-driver-doesnt-work-in-12-10) than it has to be, and the additional drivers tool dosen't always tell you correctly if the drivers are activated.While these instructions are for nvidia, this will affect most things with non free drivers which often use use dkms.

You would probably want to install the experimental 310 drivers (which rock)  if you run nvidia and test if the drivers work with something like [unigine heaven](http://unigine.com/products/heaven/) or some other benchmark EVEN IF the additional drivers tool claims the drivers are inactive.

Comment: So, I installed Additional drivers, downloaded the 310 experimental drivers as you recommended and at the end of the installation I got a [error message](http://s8.postimage.org/op1rz57kl/fffffffffffffrom_2013_02_17_00_31_15.jpg). I also have the log right [here](https://dl-web.dropbox.com/get/jockey.log?w=AADo5VWP0wxSSkb8kO3Zk1edDUQxeSzAAp3WStoaJWhbfQ) if you want.

Comment: Log link does not work. I would also try installing via apt

Comment: I can't find a valid way to get the file to the internets. If you want I'll share it with you through e-mail.

Comment: I think you linked me the 'internal' dropbox link - try shoving it in the public folder and using that, or use some flavour of pastebin.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/wGYUCNaw Ok I have the log on the internet now. By the way I tried the installation of the drivers via apt[(this one)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/202677/nvidia-driver-doesnt-work-in-12-10) and it ended up downloading drivers for a laptop (yeah I know it's weird), I know it was for a laptop because at System Settings/Displays my current screen  was recognized as "laptop" and the resolution was 1024x768 max. In System Settings/Details/Graphics the driver shown had also something to do about laptops(I didn't note it sorry).

Comment: "Module build for the currently running kernel was skipped since the kernel source for this kernel does not seem to be installed." - looks like your kernel source package wasn't installed

Comment: In additional drivers, the experimental drivers 310 are active but "not currently in use" [see?](http://s3.postimage.org/ho8gccwkj/310_drivers.jpg). But the graphical glitches are gone

Comment: Mine says the same. Does the haven benchmark perfectly, so I assume it works ;p