# Nvidia drivers on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, drivers, nvidia

I followed instructions to install nvidia drivers found here: [Nvidia driver doesn't work in 12.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202677/nvidia-driver-doesnt-work-in-12-10)
But it doesn't work for me. Same problem like in the question above: no dash and windows don't have borders.

I tried opening `nvidia-xsetting`, which asked me to run `nvidia-xconfig`. Running that did nothing but generate a broken `xorg.conf` which I had to remove because of really low resolution. I thought this is "unity not loading problem" but instead this seems to be "driver not loading problem" because `nvidia-xsetting` said that I don't use nvidia drivers (which btw I find really weird because `lsmod` says nvidia kernel module is indeed loaded), and games didn't load either.

I can "fix" this by doing `modprobe nouveau`, but with nouveau 3D games like 0 A.D. are broken.

Any ideas? I'm out of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. Problem was that nvidia cards for notebooks (I got geforce 635M) require bumblebee:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia
sudo reboot
```

After reboot run your games ( 0ad for example ) like this:

```
optirun 0ad
```

Works like charm.