# World of Warcraft under primus/crossover getting Direct3D9 is not available without opengl

Tags: nvidia-optimus, bumblebee, opengl, crossover

I'm running Ubuntu 12.10 64bit and having issues using primus (due to nvidia optimus) to run World of Warcraft in Crossover..

I'm getting the following:

```
steorra@perpetual:~$ primusrun /opt/cxoffice/bin/wine --bottle "World of Warcraft" --cx-app "Wow.exe"
p11-kit: couldn't load module: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Xlib:  extension "NV-GLX" missing on display ":0".
Direct3D9 is not available without OpenGL.
Direct3D9 is not available without OpenGL.
Direct3D9 is not available without OpenGL.
```

I've tried installing the Runtime Libraries for Direct3d9 under the relevant crossover bottle to no avail.  Help?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's possible that your drivers aren't completely installed.
Try running this if you use Nvidia cards ( 32bit, as wine uses 32bit libraries ):

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-glx
```

And this one if you use AMD/ATI cards:

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx-glx
```

You might want to re-install / update your drivers, too. You can follow one of these guides:

[Nvidia driver doesn't work in 12.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202677/nvidia-driver-doesnt-work-in-12-10)

[Nvidia drivers on Ubuntu 12.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/263174/nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-12-10)

Also try running: LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib32/nvidia-current ~/.wine/path/to/your/game

If none of these does work, try running game with `-dx9single`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am actually able to do an optirun --glxgears and see the output.. as for installing nvidia-glx, it produces a "no installation candidate" message.  I do have the nvidia ppa added as per the bumblebee instructions and well as the newest nvidia drivers.

Comment: and by adding the -dx9single onto the end of the string, amounts to exactly the same error...

Comment: Try running: LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib32/nvidia-current ~/.wine/path/to/your/game

Comment: And oh, don't forget that, you have to install nvidia-glx 32bit version, because wine uses 32bit libraries.

Comment: I solved it -- this did it:  sudo apt-get install primus-libs-ia32:i386

Comment: Ah, Good news! :D Enjoy playing, and, please, add an answer yourself, and mark it as right answer, so those who counter the same problem, won't be confused.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install primus-libs-ia32:i386
```

Answer (score -2):

after install nvidia or ati driver 
edit `.../World of Warcraft/WTF/Config.wtf` and change

```
SET gxApi "D3D9"
```

to

```
SET gxApi "OpenGL"
```